# why is memory usage changing when no code is being executed? (as3)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, memory

[image: the graph]

Hi there,
As you can see by the graph from profiler over the space of 1 minute the memory rises about 2mb and then drops back down only to rise again to the same spot. This is on an almost blank screen and no code is running. No new objects are being created. I've also noticed on iOS the CPU usage is also rising and falling in a similar pattern-from 20% up to 70%.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: You should tell us what "almost empty" means - what's on the screen *does* make a difference.

Comment: Your right! and it was what was off the screen that got me here (I didn't mention what was off the stage because I was sure nothing was really happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons. I recently had a similar situation where CPU was strangely high.

My debugging methodology was to comment out ALL code other than the boiler plate document class constructor and slowly introduce variables, classes and methods (in blocks rather than one at a time!) until the issue reappeared.

In my particular case it was to do with a network monitor class that I had incorrectly set up.

Comment: Thanks crooksy for your help. I did exactly as you suggested. 
It turned out to be an offstage MovieClip that I hadn't referenced in any code other than creating an instance.
You would assume when a display object without code is offstage it would use less cpu and ram. wouldn't you ?
Well not in this case. It had 6 tiny 10X10 Movieclip children that when on stage are always told to gotoAndStop at one of three frames. When off stage the bloody things were looping and for some reason causing these increases in memory and cpu...dang im such an idiot. Learnt a big lesson there.